# Angular attribute/property interpolation

Tags: angular

I normally do property binding like this:

```
<a [href]="myHref">Link</a>
```

(where `myHref` is a property in my Component class.)

But I've also seen

```
<a href="{{myHref}}">Link</a>
```

on the Angular website.  Which I understand.

But I've also seen this:

```
<a href={{myHref}}>Link</a>
```

(without the quotations).

It works, but I can't see this exact syntax being used on the Angular website anywhere.  Is it allowed?

Answer (score 2):

HTML attributes can be done without quotes. I don't think it has anything to do with angular.

[Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/introduction.html#intro-early-example) says

> Attributes are placed inside the start tag, and consist of a name and
>   a value, separated by an = character. The attribute value can remain
>   unquoted if it doesn’t contain spaces or any of " ' ` = < or >.
>   Otherwise, it has to be quoted using either single or double quotes.
>   The value, along with the = character, can be omitted altogether if
>   the value is the empty string.

```html
<a href=http://google.com >Google</a>
```

From [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation)

> **Interpolation** is a convenient alternative to **property binding** in many
>   cases.
>
> When rendering data values as strings, there is no technical reason to
>   prefer one form to the other. You lean toward readability, which tends
>   to favor interpolation. You suggest establishing coding style rules
>   and choosing the form that both conforms to the rules and feels most
>   natural for the task at hand.
>
> **When setting an element property to a non-string data value**, you must
>   use property binding.

Comment: Thanks.  The thing is that the `myHref` variable might contain spaces, which would make it invalid HTML, I would have thought, but it seems to work.

Comment: I think it's best if everyone would just always use quotes. More consistent and clean :) Though it doesn't matter if the interpolated value has spaces as angular compiler just sees an attribute there and always renders it with quotes anyway.

Comment: @funkizer Yes I would agree with you.